# Matching a string with Python RegEx negative lookahead

Tags: python, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I have a file with some content as wells as the two 'include' strings below:

```
some string1
some string2
...

include: "base_pricing_app_model_my_deployment_id.model.lkml"
include: "base_map_layers.model.lkml"
...
some string3
...
```

Substring "my_deployment_id" is a token I need to add to the second 'include' string so file content looks like that:

```
some string1
some string2
...

include: "base_pricing_app_model_my_deployment_id.model.lkml"
include: "base_map_layers_my_deployment_id.model.lkml"
...
some string3
```

I am running Python 3.5 and using its re library. Here is how I attempt to replace the second 'include' string:

```
with fileinput.input(files=(rfi), inplace=True) as cmodf:
for line in cmodf:
    match_no_dep_id = re.sub('^include:\s\"(?!my_deployment_id).*[.]model[.]lkml\"$', line.split('.')[0] + '_' + 'my_deployment_id' + 'model.lkml' + '"',  line)
    print(match_no_dep_id, end='')
```

However, both 'include' entries get modified and I end up with the following content:

```
some string1
some string2

include: "base_pricing_app_model_my_deployment_id_my_deployment_id.model.lkml"
include: "base_map_layers_my_deployment_id.model.lkml"

some string3
...
```

So my negative lookahead regexp matches both strings, including the one which already contains the token I am negating.

I am not sure what I am missing here.
Please help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want is `^include:\s\".*(?<!my_deployment_id)\.model\.lkml\"$`

With yours (i.e. `^include:\s\"(?!my_deployment_id).*[.]model[.]lkml\"$`), you are filtering out entries like these `include: "include: "my_deployment_id.base_map_layers.model.lkml"` (Notice my_deployment_id comes before and not right before `.model.lkml`)

```
In [1]: string1 = 'include: "base_pricing_app_model_my_deployment_id.model.lkml"'
   ...: string2 = 'include: "base_map_layers.model.lkml"'
   ...: 
   ...: import re
   ...: 
   ...: 
   ...: def clean_include(include: str) -> str:
   ...:     return re.sub(
   ...:         '^include:\s\".*(?<!my_deployment_id)\.model\.lkml\"$',
   ...:         include.split('.')[0] + '_' + 'my_deployment_id' + '.model.lkml' + '"',
   ...:         include,
   ...:     )
   ...: 
   ...: 
   ...: print(clean_include(string1))
   ...: print(clean_include(string2))
   ...: 
   ...: 
include: "base_pricing_app_model_my_deployment_id.model.lkml"
include: "base_map_layers_my_deployment_id.model.lkml"
```